# How to read a value based on a key in application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have to read a value based on a key in the `application.yaml` file.
For example, it should be something like this:

```
map: {key: "value"}
```

How should I define my corresponding Java POJO class to read this?

**NOTE: I have a `Map` where I need to search a user-name based on user-id**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you've a couple of questions out. Please format code/JSON properly (e.g by using _backticks_). This clarifies your question and raises your chances for an answer

Answer (score 0):

Using application.yml vs application.properties in Spring Boot
try this one:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-yaml-vs-properties